# How to insert a html code after the page is rendered

Tags: ionic-framework

I am trying to insert a piece of html code (ion-header-bar) after i click on login button . I need this code to be added on top of all the modules. As it is a same piece of code in all the modules, is there anyway to achieve it by writing it in a single place rather than adding the repeated code to all the modules.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT I realize that the question did not clarify which version of ionic is used. **This answer** is **only** working **for ionic 2 and ionic 3** (and possibly later versions) - ionic 1 will work differently

if you follow the typical structure of an Ionic 2 or 3 Project (with an `App.component` using `<ion-nav>`) you would just put the `<ion-header-bar>` next to your `<ion-nav>` with an `*ngIf`:

```
/// src/app/app.html
<ion-header-bar *ngIf="isUserLoggedIn()">This only shows when is UserLoggedIn() returns true</ion-header-bar>
<ion-nav [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>
```

And inside your `app.component.ts` you just implement the function used by the `*ngIf`

```
/// src/app/app.component.ts
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  public rootPage: any = MenuPage;

  public isUserLoggedIn(): boolean {
      // TODO: Implement this to return true when the user is logged in
  }

}
```

there are many ways to do this - but this is about the simplest I can think of right now, given the limited information you provided.

Comment: Could you please explain for ionic 1 frwk. moreover, i dont have any ion nav bar in my code , i just have a header bar and i want to reuse the header bar code in a single place, so that i dont have to repeat the same code in all the modules.

Answer (score 0):

I created a codepen for this: 
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aEYBmL

In your HTML add ng-if to your header bar and give it a function that just returns true when the user is logged in:

```
<html>
(...)
  <body ng-controller="MyCtrl">

    <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive" ng-if="isUserLoggedIn()">
      <h1 class="title">this only shows if isUserLoggedIn() returns true</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>

    <ion-content>
      <h1 style="margin-top: 56px">Here is your other content!</h1>
    </ion-content>

  </body>
</html>
```

then attach that function or variable to your scope inside your controller:

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.isUserLoggedIn = () => {
    // TODO Implement this
    return true;
  }
});
```

read about ng-if here:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf

**EDIT: Displaying a component on every screen:**

Look at this codepen:
https://codepen.io/calendee/pen/ubzDq

here you have your `ion-nav-navbar` (which is simmilar to a `ion-header-bar` with a backbutton and a title) outside of `ion-nav-bar`, which makes it display all the time - without putting it everywhere

```
///This wont be replaced as its not inside the ion-nav-view. So its displayed on every screen.
<ion-nav-bar>
 <ion-nav-back-button>
 </ion-nav-back-button>
</ion-nav-bar>

<ion-nav-view>
/// Everything in here will be replaced by your current navstack
</ion-nav-view>
```

Comment: but how would this affect in all the modules. My question here is to show the SAME header bar on top of all the modules.The above example would just be a single piece of code . I dont want to rewrite this code in all the modules. Is it possible?To be more precise, I have a menu bar with 5 modules, i want the above header bar to be shown on top of all the 5 modules.Although I have a separate html for each module, I have to repeat the common header bar ,<h1 class="title">Common Name Shared by all the modules</h1> in all the modules. I am looking for a way to have it as a common code.

Comment: Your answer is mostly inclined towards isUserLoggedIn function, but my query is totally different